# Desseleccionar radio button html

Tags: html, bootstrap

con este codigo puedo seleccionar una sola opcion.
¿como deselecciono la que seleccion? o volverlas todas blancas

```html
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Tipo" value=1>1
            </label><br />
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Tipo" value=2>2
            </label><hr />
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Tipo" value=3>3
            </label><br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

si lo hago en javascript como añado a la estructura:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html
```

Comment: Si quieres quitar la selección a un radio debes usar javascript o jquery para eso, usando checkbox podrías seleccionar y desseleccionar las veces que quieras

Comment: @CamiloVasquez como lo haria usando jquery, ?? estoy aprendiendo

Comment: Como te dice @CamiloVasquez has de usar JS, con un boton, o checkbox asociado al codigo para deseleccionar los radiobutton... investiga, **intentalo** y si tienes problemas , edita la pregunta para explicarlos segun [ask] para poder ayudarte. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
espero te ayude:

<html>
<head>
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function unselect() {
                document.querySelectorAll('[name=Tipo]').forEach((x) => x.checked = false);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Tipo" value=1>1
            </label><br />
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Tipo" value=2>2
            </label><hr />
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Tipo" value=3>3
            </label><br />
            <hr/>
            <button id="unselect" onclick="unselect()">Desseleccionar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes una forma de anular la selección utilizando javascript, sin ninguna librería.

No tienes más que poner la propiedad `checked` de cada radio a `false`:

```js
function unselect(){
  document.querySelectorAll('[name=Tipo]').forEach((x) => x.checked=false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Tipo" value=1>1
            </label><br />
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Tipo" value=2>2
            </label><hr />
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Tipo" value=3>3
            </label><br />
            <hr/>
            <button id="unselect" onclick="unselect()">Desseleccionar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: como lo hago ?? edite la pregunta para adjuntarla en la estructura

Comment: Debes incluir el código javascript en un tag script: `<script type="text/javascript">.....</script>` Generalmente se suele incluir dentro del `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas controlar individualmente tus radio button puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="Tipo" value=1>1
   </label><br />
   <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="Tipo" value=2>2
   </label><hr />
   <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="Tipo" value=3>3
   </label><br />
   <hr/>
 </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   let radios = document.querySelectorAll("[type='radio']");
   radios.forEach((x)=>{
     x.dataset.val = x.checked; // guardamos el estado del radio button dentro del elemento
     x.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
       let element = e.target;
       if(element.dataset.val == 'false'){
         element.dataset.val = 'true';
         element.checked = true;
       }else{
         element.dataset.val = 'false';
         element.checked = false;
       }
     },true);
   });
</scrip>
```

Lo que estamos haciendo es controlando individualmente cada radio button, guardando su estado anterior y actualizándolo cada vez que hacemos click en el elemento.